# R Dataframe comparison which, scaling bad

Tags: r, dplyr

The idea is extracting the position of df charactes with a reference of other df, example:

```
L<-LETTERS[1:25]
A<-c(1:25)
df<-data.frame(L,A)
Compare<-c(LETTERS[sample(1:25, 25)])
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[i,1]<-which(df[i,1]==Compare)
}
head(df)

   L A
1 14 1
2 12 2
3  2 3
```

This works good but scale very bad, like all for, any ideas with apply, or dplyr?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your intended output?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `match`

**Your data** (use `set.seed` when providing data using `sample`)

```
df <- data.frame(L = LETTERS[1:25], A = 1:25)
set.seed(1)
Compare <- LETTERS[sample(1:25, 25)]
```

**Solution**

```
df$L <- match(df$L, Compare)
head(df)
#    L A
# 1 10 1
# 2 23 2
# 3 12 3
# 4 11 4
# 5  5 5
# 6 21 6
```

Comment: Thank you David! It was this! Thank you so much!